# How do i use Scripts in mvc. not inline script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I wrote js code in MyScript.js and how I can make my script run when page load?
and how I can make script file run in my mvc?
I hope I can get a precise answer and understand that good.
When I did on regular html and not in mvc it works very well
the two js file i would like to use are

`1. jquery.zaccordion.js`

`2. MyScript.js`

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title> 
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery-1.8.2.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery.zaccordion.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/MyScript.js")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
@RenderSection("MyScript", required: false)
</head>

<body>
<header>
<div class="site-logo">
  <img class="img-logo-size" src="Images/logo.png" alt="" />
 </div>
<div class="manu">
     <div class="nav-tabs">
         <div class="hoverBtn">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</div>
         <div class="hoverBtn">@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</div>
         <div class="hoverBtn">@Html.ActionLink("Contact","Contact","Home")</div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-border">
        <ul id="splash">
            <li>
                <img class="img-size" src="../Images/TM-front-image-World-network.jpg" alt="" />
                <div>
                    <strong>Old School Diner</strong>
                    <p class="splash-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras porttitor lacus sollicitudin ligula sagittis a ultricies nulla ultricies. Ut odio nisi, posuere sed blandit at, bibendum non dolor.</p>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img class="img-size" src="../Images/banner-your-it-11.jpg" alt="" />
                <div>
                    <strong>A Day at the Pool</strong>
                    <p class="splash-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras in condimentum sem. Aenean faucibus dignissim auctor. In ut libero vitae augue laoreet iaculis at a tellus.</p>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img class="img-size" src="../Images/network1.png" alt="" />
                <div>
                    <strong>Fill it Up!</strong>
                    <p class="splash-text">Duis viverra velit orci. Sed vestibulum mi nec est imperdiet sed ullamcorper augue molestie. Donec ultrices facilisis erat at porttitor.</p>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img class="img-size" src="../Images/1338453958network_header.jpg" alt="" />
                <div>
                    <strong>Going for a Drive</strong>
                    <p class="splash-text">Phasellus sed lectus nisl, eget cursus eros. Suspendisse posuere orci eu lorem luctus et porta nunc posuere. Cras sed lectus vitae leo accumsan adipiscing.</p>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</header>

<div class="page-wrap">
    @RenderBody()
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    @RenderSection("MyScript", required: false)
</div>

<footer>
    <div class="site-footer">
        <div class="float-left">
            <p>&copy;@DateTime.Now.Year-Erez Gershon</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Thanks for all

Comment: in which directory your script files exist?

Comment: You have duplicate scripts (`@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery-1.8.2.js")` and `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")`) and also duplicate `@RenderSection()` Render all your scripts in one place (in the `<head>` or immediately before the closing `</body>` tag) and in the correct order

Comment: they are in scripts folder
the scrip (@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery-1.8.2.js") and @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")) are showing by defualt mvc and also te render section but i can delete if thats what i need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this line to work `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/MyScript.js")` you have to register `MyScript.js` to bundle in `BundleConfig.cs` file.

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/MyScript.js").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/MyScript.js")); // make sure that this is your path to MyScript.js
```

---

If you want to use `@RenderSection("MyScript", required: false)`, it's a section that will be rendered in a view, like below. But if you want to add `MyScript.js` you have to include that line of code inside the `section`.

```
@section MyScript {
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/MyScript.js")
}
```

**Note:** Every new script you add in your project that you want to use it with `@Scripts.Render` you have to include in `BundleConfig`.

Comment: i have to them both? if i register my script to bundles i dont need to use rendersection?

Comment: @Erez you don't need to use `RenderSection`, this is for another purpose. To include your `<script />` tag, you have to use `@Scripts.Render`.